# Laravel with multiple database

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have laravel project used for apis(Passport). It uses multiple databases one database stores user information and the database name for that user. I created a `BaseController`, all the other controllers extends from this controller. But I am not able to fetch `Auth::id();` from the `BaseController`. How can I get the `Auth::id` in the constructor?

```
class BaseController extends Controller

{  
     protected $companySchema;

     public function __construct() {        
     $user =  \App\User::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
     $company =  $user->company;
     $this->companySchema = $company->cmp_Schema;    
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After laravel 5.3.4 you can't use `Auth::user()` in the constructor because the middleware isn't run yet.

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() { 

        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->companySchema = Auth::user()->company->cmp_Schema;

            return $next($request);
        });

    }

}
```

try this code and tell me if it works

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Auth` in constructor, because middleware is not run yet. its from 5.3

check this link : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors

Answer (score 0):

First you should setup a connection in `config/database.php`:

```
    'my_new_connection' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => $your_db_name,
        'username' => $your_db_username,
        'password' => $your_db_password,
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Then you can change default database connection dynamically by this:

```
Config::set('database.default', 'my_new_connection');
```

Answer (score -1):

You should first call

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

which is returning you the current user model associated, which is normally  User. Then following should work:

```
$user->id
```

Comment: $user = Auth::user(); returns null